# iOS - run multiple async requests at the same time

Tags: ios, asynchronous, nsmutableurlrequest

I'm a beginning iOS developer and in my first app I want to load data for my view controller, but the problem is that the data comes over from three different web services. I use `NSMutableRequest` in an attempt to implement this functionality.

What I want to do is issue three requests to load data at the same time and when the last one finishes, remove the activity indicator.

I tried using an NSOperationQueue, but with async it doesn't execute the `didReceiveData` or `didFailWithError` methods. Please do comment if you need more detail or explanation (my English is not very good).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at GCD, and create 1 synchronous request that contains your 3 asynchronous requests to your web services.  This way you let GCD do the work of waiting for each of the async operations to complete.  There are a few really good videos on itunes from WWDC (Apple's developer conference) that are incredibly informative with regard to GCD.

Comment: There is a concrete example ? Thanks